# How to select into a table the code within a procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem for school in which I am being asked to select into a table the code inside a procedure with a certain String in the name of the procedure, I've searched around but can't find any documentation on how to this in the `sys.` documentation.

For clarification, what I need to do is fill a column with the code from a procedure whose name has a certain String.

Comment: Is there any way you can illustrate this with an example because I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Do you mean you want to search all the stored procs in the database looking for those that contain a certain string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sys.sql_modules` has the code of every module defined in your SQL server. But since you need to search by the name of the procedure I have joined it with `sys.objects` as well.

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.name AS 'Object Name',m.definition AS 'Code'
FROM sys.sql_modules m 
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON m.object_id=o.object_id
WHERE o.name Like '%@Search%'
```